# Ajax loaded forms not posts data via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, html, codeigniter, jquery

Hi im using codeigniter and built ajax infinite scroll. and having comment forms on that ajax scrolls, my concern is when page loads, 10 posts would be loaded and if scrolled down another 10 post would get loaded and now all 20 posts would contain their own comment forms. im using ajax to post the comments. so for 1st 10 posts which is loaded when page loaded comment forms is working but for ajax loaded posts comment form ajax post is not working. below is the code im using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.post_comment').click(function() {
  var form_data = {
    csrfsecurity: $(this).parent().find("input[name=csrfsecurity]").val(),
    post_text: $(this).parent().find('.comment_text').val()    
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('/comment'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response){
      $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

the below form would load 10 times when scroll the page down

```
<form action="http://localhost/comment" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="comment_text" value="" id="comment_text" size="35" class="comment_text">
<input type="submit" id="post_comment" name="post_comment" value="submit comment" class="post_comment" >
</form>
```

Comment: My guess is that you are not adding the event listener to the HTML you are AJAXing in. Your first ten work because you are adding the event listener for the original 10 on document load.

Comment: how to do it? @thatidiotguy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax infinite scroll jquery not work for forms loaded from ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208990/ajax-infinite-scroll-jquery-not-work-for-forms-loaded-from-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not adding the event listener to the HTML you are AJAXing in. Your first ten work because you are adding the event listener for the original 10 on document load.

You will need to run the jquery code adding the event handlers to the DOM elements (elements with class post_comment it looks like) click events again.

Comment: @vinothkumar What? You already have the code. You wrote it did you not?